# completely remove a label

Tags: tkinter, memory, label

I am writing a program to display 30 years of holiday photos.

1. First display the thirty directories as radiobuttons and get user to choose one
2. then display all thumbnails (up to 500) within the chosen directory as radiobuttons and get the user to choose one
3. then before doing fun things clear out the radiobuttons and this is where I have a problem

In the code below I have stripped out (hopefully) all the distractions.  When run, output is

```
.!label2.!radiobutton
.!label2.!radiobutton1
.!label2.!radiobutton2
restart
.!label3.!radiobutton
.!label3.!radiobutton1
.!label3.!radiobutton2
restart
.!label4.!radiobutton
.!label4.!radiobutton1
.!label4.!radiobutton2
```

Tried putting "label" as a global entity to no effect

any advice or suggestions gratefully received as I have been on this for about a week now
also pointers to further reading welcomed

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
dir_list = ['Hebrides','Berlin','Malaysia']
var=StringVar()

def radiobuttons():
    label=Label(root)
    for x in (dir_list):
        r = Radiobutton(label,text=x, value=x,variable=var)
        print(r)
label.destroy()

def restart():
    print("restart")
    label.destroy()
    radiobuttons()

label=Label(root)
radiobuttons()
restart()
restart()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: sorry.....the line "label.destroy" after "print(r)" should not be there....my bad

Comment: on rereading probably my question is unclear, why does the output show label2 then label3 then label4 should the labels not be destroyed between each iteration ?